# Draw - how to connect view class to the activity

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android studio and I'm having problem with drawing. I understood that "onDraw()" function can only be implemented in class that extendes "View". But I don't under how do I connect my activity to the view class, so we will see on the screen the view class, not the activity one.
Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can attach the View in your XML.

Comment: @MalithLakshan How do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty much basic thing android. You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

I'll just show you an example.

First the View class,

```
public MyView extends View{
     public MyView(Context context,AttributeSet set){
         super(context,set);
     }

     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
         //draw the item
     }
}
```

In XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://www....."
     android:orientation="veretical"
     android:width="match_parent" 
     android:height="match_parent">

     <!--you custom view here-->
     <com.your.package.name.MyView
         android:width="match_parent"
         android:height="match_parent"/>         

</LinearLayout>
```

Use this XML as the content view of your activity.

Comment: Thanks! Is the XML is another layout, seperate from the activity one?

Comment: No its the same activity layout. Refer the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your's custom view object to realtive layout.Hear Relative is where you want to see canvas it may complete layout or portion of the layout

```
   RelativeLayout viewlayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewlayoutid);
   viewlayout.addView(new yours_customviewclass(this,null));//yours_customviewclass is your custom view means which extends view class,overide ondraw methods in this class
```

Comment: In the "yours_customvewclass" do I need to write the name of the class?

Comment: yes that is a class where you have extended the View class and implements ondraw method

Comment: Ok great :) I'll check that out. Thanks!